# What is the name of the purple flower that opens in the morning and closes in the evening?

Tags: identification, flowers

I have this in my home. I am interested in getting more information about it, particularly what time it opens in the day and what time it closes. The interesting thing I noticed, it opens up with the daylight and it closes during daylight in the evening. Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: I can't see the leaves properly to ID, but from your descripion, most likely Ipomea (morning glory) of some variety, assuming it's a climber. Need more info really.

Comment: @Bamboo this looks like it. I will post a clear picture later today to help identify exactly. You can post that as answer and I will accept. [This is is it-wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_glory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I suppose I'm obliged to post it as an official answer, or it remains technically unanswered. Okay, it's [Ipomoea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea) of some variety - as to which, could be [*I. indica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_indica), or [*I. purpurea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipomoea_purpurea). Usually, the flowers open in the morning (hence the common name Morning Glory) and close by the afternoon.